# What causes ducks to randomly swear sometimes?

Tags: duck-game

Occasionally while playing, ducks will make random beeping noises as if a swear word was being censored. Sometimes it happens when slipping on a banana, but for the most part it seems to be entirely random.

What causes ducks to swear sometimes? Does something cause it to happen, or is it completely random?

Comment: This is kind of a game design question, like why make the ducks 'seem to swear'

Comment: @n_palum I've edited my question to clarify that I'm looking for the in-game circumstances that can cause this to happen, rather than the reason *why* it happens

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The swearing in duck game is often caused by an item being thrown at your duck, or some other similar mishap. It tends to be physical punishment done to the duck that involves tripping over (I.e. with a banana peel) or being hit by an item.

Linked to your [other question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/316377/what-does-the-smiley-face-slider-do), the frequency of swearing is controlled by the angry happy face slider found in your profile editor [(Source)](https://steamcommunity.com/app/312530/discussions/0/618463738399170603/)