# What does the smiley face slider do?

Tags: duck-game

When creating a new user profile in Duck Game, there's an adjustable slider bar with an happy face on the left and an an angry face on the right.

Does this slider do anything?

[image: Smiley face slider]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the FAQ [here](https://steamcommunity.com/app/312530/discussions/0/618463738399170603/):

> Controls the frequency of how often your duck "curses"

For an example, your duck can curse when an item is thrown at them. If the slider is more to the angry side, this happens more often.

The cursing in the game sounds like an audible bleep, as if they've been censored [(Source)](https://www.reddit.com/r/duckgame/comments/3fdkz0/what_the_hell_is_the_mood_slider_and_why_the_hell/ctvsens/).